# vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter with SetOperationToDifference operating on identical vtkPolyData

Tags: vtk

Is there a way to set up a vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter so that, when it is used to take a boolean difference between identical vtkPolyData, it will result in an empty vtkPolyData?  For instance, if I start with `vtkPolyData * output` and do ...

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter> diffFilter = 
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter>::New();
diffFilter->SetOperationToDifference();
diffFilter->SetInputData(0,output1);
diffFilter->SetInputData(1,output1); // set input and output to same geometry
```

... the result of the `diffFilter` operation appears to be identical to `output1`.  For my application, the result should be an empty set.

According to this VTK Journal article http://www.vtkjournal.org/browse/publication/797  the algorithm assumes there are no coplanar triangles, so it may be that what I ask is impossible, and I need to look at a CSG-based library.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by Cory Quammen on the vtk-users mailing list:

> It would be *possible* to do as a preprocessing step prior to the main
>   algorithm, but as it exists now, the filter should fail miserably, I
>   suspect.
>
> Perhaps this filter by Ronald Römer would do the right thing in this
>   case?
>
> https://github.com/zippy84/vtkbool